# Why do we preform row reduction on $A^t$ for solving $A^tCAx = f$

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm trying to learn linear algebra using the MIT OCW lectures and while it can be difficult, I've been managing so far.
I got to the [12th problem set](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/ax-b-and-the-four-subspaces/graphs-networks-incidence-matrices/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses1.12sol.pdf) and I'm stuck on the 2nd problem.

I know one way to solve $Ax = b$ is by appending b to the end of A, preforming row reduction, setting free variables to 0 etc., but I don't understand why we do it $A^t$ when solving $A^tCAx = f$. Doesn't $A^tCA$  as a whole function as an $A$ in a regular $Ax = b$?

When I do preform the row reduction by hand, I get the free variable in the 4th column, so why does the solution say we take $x_3 = 0$ and not $x_4$?

EDIT: The solution with $x_4 = 0$ works, but why is $x_3 = 0$ chosen?